# Manually load the fragment in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, vertical-scrolling

I want Horizontal as well as vertical swipe using the ViewPager.I implemented it using the Vertical view pager in which I used the fragments for the vertical swipe and in that fragments, used ViewPager for the horizontal swipe.

I took help from below link for vertical swipe:
https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/
and http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/ for horizontal swipe.

Problem:

I have three image adapters and three fragments, one for each image adapter. These three fragments are inside one FragmentActivity. When this FragmentActivity is created I want to manually select which fragment should be displayed. Here, the three fragments contains data with three different languages. Now I want to load the fragment of particular language specified by the user. Any example or a code snippet will help me implement this functionality.

Thanks in advance :)